# How to start executing a block of code after changing the value of MutableLiveData when using .observeAsState()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to start executing a block of code after changing the value of MutableLiveData when using .observeAsState()?

Example: MutableLiveData changes and after need to call Toast.

```
@Composable
fun TextInfo() {
    val isSuccess by remember { viewModel.isSuccess.observeAsState() }//var isSuccess = MutableLiveData<Boolean>() — in ViewModel

    LaunchedEffect(isSuccess) {
        Log.d("IS SUCCESS", "trues")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing a Toast is a side effect, so you need to put it inside a LaunchedEffect. Make the LiveData state the key of the LaunchedEffect. This causes the side effect to only occur when this particular LiveData's value changes.

```
val myDataState = remember { someLiveData.observeAsState() }
LaunchedEffect(myDataState) {
    // show the toast
}
```

Read about it in the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Comment: Oh, I forgot about LaunchedEffect actually :) Thank you

Comment: @tenfour04 I get the error «Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun <T> remember(calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)»

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the context of where you’re calling this?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I changed the question.